# Use document.elementFromPoint to check if an element at specific co-ordinates has a particular class

Tags: javascript

I have coordinates. I want to check if there's an element with a specific class at these coordinates. How would I do this?

I've tried the following code (and here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0o160f5g/2/):

HTML:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
if(document.elementFromPoint(30, 30) == ".foo"){
    alert("The red square is within the coordinates")
}else{
    alert("The red square is outside the coordinates")
}
```

This code should give the alert "The red square is within the coordinates". However it gives the alert "The red square is outside the coordinates". What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint#Return_value) returns an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object (or null), not a css selector. So you would test the various properties of that element to see if it matched

```
//checks class
document.elementFromPoint(30,30).classList.contains('foo')
//checks id
document.elementFromPoint(30,30).id == 'foo'
//test for null first so not to get type errors 
var eleAtPoint = document.elementFromPoint(30,30);
if(eleAtPoint && eleAtPoint.classList.contains("foo")){
   //do something.
}
```

Or if you already have an element in mind compare a reference you already have with the result of elementFromPoint

```
var elementToCheck = document.querySelector('.foo');

if(document.elementFromPoint(30,30) === elementToCheck){
  //do something.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So it's basically: `if(document.elementFromPoint(30, 30).classList.contains("foo")){alert("The red square is within the coordinates")}`

Comment: Yes, but like in the 3rd example I would check to make sure that it has actually returned an element first before trying to use any of the properties. Otherwise you might end up trying to use a null value because it didnt actually find an element at that spot.

Answer (score 1):

> The elementFromPoint() method of the Document interface returns the topmost element at the specified coordinates.

You should compare this with another element:

```
   if(document.elementFromPoint(30, 30) == document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0]){
        alert("The red square  is within the coordinates")
    }else{
        alert("The red square is outside the coordinates")
    }
```

Comment: I believe that it should be better `document.elementFromPoint(30, 30).className === "classname"` since if there are more than one element with the same class wont match